# ASP.NET MVC4 Controller methods return concrete types instead of JSON in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I make a controller method return a list of objects and do something to it before sending the result back to the browser?

Changing the return type of a controller method from JsonResult to List will return the type of the result "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyObject]" in the request.

I am trying to do it through a custom result filter but when the result gets to the filter OnResultExecuted method, it is already jsonified to the text above. Is there anything I can do in the OnResultExecuting method to retrieve the list returned from the method and modify it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not make your modifications to the objects in the action/method before passing it to the `JsonResult`

Comment: I need the methods to return concrete types instead of JsonResult. The reason I am doing this is because I need to wrap the controller in an interface which will be shared with a proxy for the controller. It's very specific to the application I am working at.

Comment: can you clarify why you are returning the `List` as apposed to the `JsonResult`

Comment: Like I said in the comment above, I am wrapping the controller (CtrlA) in an interface(ICtrl), which will also be implemented by another class (ProxyB). I can make the methods in ICtrl return JsonResult, then deserialize when the methods are called through ProxyB. Or I am hoping I can return concrete types in the CtrlA and serialize results outside of the controller, maybe via a filter attribute. Can you recommend a better approach if this doesn't make sense? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Create a dependency service like `ICtrlService` which will have a method that returns the type you want. `List<MyObject> ICtrlService.SomeMethod()` and inject it into the controller, which will pass the JsonResult like it's suppose to. By using the  `ICtrlService` you make the functionality reusable so that ProxyB can use it

Comment: In addition to reusability, we are making both classes implement the same interface to keep ProxyB synced with CtrlA. Injecting the dependency into the controller does not seem to enforce that tho.

Comment: The purpose of the controller is to pass and read data between the view and model. Asp.net mvc follows a convention to achieve this using their framework. Making your controllers inherit from your intended interface will cause confusions between what is the intended purpose of your controller as from what you describe you have other intentions for the interface.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand from the comments, I think you are looking to do something like this

```
public interface ICtrlService {
    List<MyObject> SomeMethod();
}


public ControllerA : Controller {
    ICtrlService service;

    public MyController(ICtrlService service){
        this.service = service
    }

    public JsonResult SomeAction() {
        List<MyObject> result = service.SomeMethod();
        return Json(result);
    }
}
```

Your proxy can implement the service as stated.

```
public class ProxyB : ICtrlService {

    public List<MyObject> SomeMethod() {...}

}
```

You could even use the proxy as the injected dependency to your controller making sure that the controller will actually be providing the needed functionality.

Or use the common service as a dependency for your proxy.

```
public class ProxyB {
    ICtrlService service;
    public ProxyB(ICtrlService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public List<MyObject> SomeProxyMethod() {
        var result = service.SomeMethod();    
        //...Do what you want with object
        return result;
    }
}
```

This will save the proxy from having to make calls to the controller as it will have access to the same common service functionality.

Comment: I agree that by doing what I described, we are complicating the controller. In our case, ProxyB is actually a proxy that makes requests to CtrlA. They will have the same method signatures but different implementations. Wrapping them in the same interface is meant to enforce syncing between the two classes. Maybe there is a better way of achieving this. I will try to look for more information. Thanks for the comments and answer!

Comment: Glad to help. If you found this answer useful feel free to up vote. Thanks.